# Windows Phone Background services

Tags: windows-phone-8, download, background-process

I am trying to make a application which downloads files as per the URL's provided. I have 3 different parts (Forms in windows, activities in android) namely pdf, image and text where I am downloading respective type of files.

I am trying to achieve following

While I start download in PDF section, download should start in background and I should be able to navigate to next form and start download in image section, while images and pdf's are getting downloaded, I should be able to move to text form and start text download.

So In short I am trying to make a application which will keep downloading the files in the background even if application closes or pause.

I did this in Android using Bound Services (BIND.AUTO.CREATE) and Async Task.

I am new to Windows phone 8 and I am trying to make the same thing work in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Background file transfers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).